# how to create square flexible image buttons

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create a screen for application where main part of the screen is 4x4 image buttons.
I want that 4 buttons will fill 90% width of the screen and each button will be a square. 
I use table layout for the table of buttons and layout_weight to make it proper width. How can I make width and high of the buttons the same?

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_1_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_1_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_1_3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton_1_4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
        </TableRow>
```

...

Comment: Show the xml you have tried

Comment: show your xml or image of layout you want

Comment: I added the code. In my case android:layout_weight="0.25" 4 times is 100%, but for some reason it makes some margin around so it is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know how to put buttons that fill 90% width of the screen but you don't know how to set the height so that the button will be a square, right? If so, I think you have to set the height via coding. The first step is to get the width of the buttons, then set their height.